# Adding "key" attribute to properties in a base class in MVC 4 for Entity Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I have a .dll with a class in it, which contains a list of objects (this is from metadata, I don't have source code):

```
public class APIKeyInfo
{
    public APIKeyInfo();
    public long AccessMask { get; set; }
    public List<AccountEntry> Characters { get; set; }
    public DateTime Expires { get; set; }
}

public class AccountEntry
{
    public AccountEntry();
    public long CharacterID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ... other properties
}
```

Now in my code, I have an extended class of APIKeyInfo, which specifies a database table using EF Code First:

```
[Table("MyApiKey")]
public class MyApiKey : APIKeyInfo
{
    [Key]
    public int KeyId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string vCode { get; set; } 
}
```

The problem is that this causes EF to give me an error saying that when it tries to create a table for the "List Characters" property inside APIKeyInfo (which I assume just has a FK to the MyApiKey table), it says that the key has not been defined. So, my question is, how can I specify the key for the "List Characters" property when I don't have access to the source code? I would hope for something like:

```
[Table("MyApiKey")]
public class MyApiKey : APIKeyInfo
{
    [Key]
    public int KeyId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string vCode { get; set; } 

    [Key]
    base.Characters.CharacterID;
}
```

to just tell it which property to use, but obviously that doesn't work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't use code first if you don't control the source code of the entities...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not actually tried this, But I don't see why it wouldn't work.
Instead of using the Attributes, Try using the EntityTypeConfiguration objects
e.g.

```
 public class MyApiKeyMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyApiKey>
 {
     public MyApiKeyMapping()
     {
         this.ToTable("MyApiKey");
         this.HasKey(k => k.KeyId);
         this.Property(p => p.vCode).IsRequired();
     }
}

public class AccountEntryMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<AccountEntry>
{
    public AccountEntryMapping()
    {
        this.ToTable("AccountEntry");
        this.HasKey(k => k.CharacterId);
    }
}
```

that should let you create the mappings for entities you don't own (Hopefully).

then in your context you simply add the following.

```
public class MyApiContext : DbContext
{

    ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MyApiKeyMapping());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AccountEntryMapping());
    }
}
```

you can also add relationships and any other properties you need to  set to the mappings.

Comment: It worked! Excellent answer, this lets me add any other properties I need to.

Comment: I just discovered an issue with this. When I save the new item to the database, it's overwriting the "KeyID" that I give it and using an auto-generated key. Is there a way to tell it not to do that?

Comment: Yes you can specify a property to not let the database autogenerate keys. `this.Property(x => x.KeyId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);` (I think off the top of my head)

Comment: Yes I tried that, but all it does is cause it to overwrite my given value with a "1" every time instead of an incrementing value.

Comment: After looking at the database schema, it seems it's making the KeyId (primary key) field an Identity field, which is why it's overwriting it. I need to find a way to stop it from make it an Identity. EDIT: nevermind, it was just keeping old settings and I had to entirely delete the database. Works now.